# Android aar Library gradle dependencies vs android project gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar, android-multidex

I have created a android library and created aar file which has gradle dependencies of Glide library and when I use this aar as a library in my main project.But when i use the part of glide code in the library, it gives an error as no class found.When add the gradle dependency of glide library in the main project it works fine.Will this cause multidex issues?

Comment: run 'gradle dependencies',paste your dependence tree here.

Answer (score 2):

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

You should use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.